# How to change a div background image while hover without jQuery?

Tags: css, image, background

I want to change the background of a DIV on hover event. Is there a way to do this using pure CSS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, this is pretty easy with pure CSS, albeit IE6, if I remember rightly, doesn't support `:hover` on any elements except for `a`. But the following should work consistently in other browsers:

```
div {
    background: #fff url(path/to/image.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

div:hover {
    background: #ffa url(path/to/hoverImage.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```